# The 'if' Statement is Redundant

Tags: java, if-statement

I am trying to code a validation system to validate if the user has inputted in the fields required. I seem to be getting an error "The 'if' Statement is Redundant" can someone help me fix this problem? Or maybe come up with a better way of validating the fields to check if the fields are not empty.

```
String messageId = messageIdText.getText();
String subject = subjectText.getText();
String recipient = recipientText.getText();
String message = messageArea.getText();
boolean allFieldsCheck = false;

if (messageId.equals("") ){
    allFieldsCheck = false;
} else {
    allFieldsCheck = true;
}
if (subject.equals("") ){
    allFieldsCheck = false;
} else {
    allFieldsCheck = true;
}
if (recipient.equals("") ){
    allFieldsCheck = false;
} else {
    allFieldsCheck = true;
}
if (message.equals("") ){
    allFieldsCheck = false;
} else {
    allFieldsCheck = true;
}
```

Comment: `if (cond) { x = true; } else { x = false; }` is equivalent to `x = cond;`.

Comment: Also, only your final check has any effect on the overall result.

Comment: Apparently you want to set `allFieldsCheck = true` once in the beginning and remove all `else` branches.

Comment: Also `allFieldsCheck = !messageId.isEmpty()` (and so on) is more elegant, shorter and more readable.

Comment: Please post a complete example that others can try compiling on their own, and please flag the line which gets the error

Comment: @MiserableVariable All four `if` blocks do.

Comment: If you're going to be doing this sort of thing a lot, you might think about writing a helper method along the lines of `public boolean checkEmpty(String... fields) { // check for emptiness }`

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, you can omit all but the last `if` statement, since it will override whatever value you had on `allFieldsCheck` anyway. But even so, you don't need an `if` statement - you could just assign the value of a boolean check to the variable directly:

```
allFieldsCheck = !message.equals("");
```

Having stated that, I assume that what you meant to do is validate that no field equals to `""`. This can be done with a series of logical operators instead of `if` statements:

```
boolean allFieldsCheck = !(messageId.equals("") ||
                           subject.equals("") ||
                           recipient.equals("") ||
                           message.equals(""));
```

Comment: As preference, and where I find it reads more clear, I normally express `!(a || b || c)` as `!a && !b && !c`.

Comment: And it is better* to use `#isEmpty()` instead of `#equals("")`. (* more readable)

Answer (score 1):

One issue is the 3 first if statements are redundant because the 4th if statement will override any changes they make.

It seems you want to assign allFieldsCheck to false if any of these values are empty. Here would be a much simpler one liner. Basically if any value is empty string than the allFieldsCheck is set to false.

```
 allFieldsCheck = !(messageId.equals("") || subject.equals("")|| message.equals("") || subject.equals(""))
```

Answer (score 0):

Booleans in java can be declared this way:

```
boolean myBool = some condition;
```

Ex.

```
boolean myBool = 5 + 1 == 6; // myBool = true
```

So your `if` statements can be compressed to look like this:

```
allFieldsCheck = !messageId.equals("");
```

Or all of them compressed into one:

```
allFieldsCheck = !messageId.equals("") && !subject.equals("") && !recipient.equals("") && !message.equals("");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String messageId = messageIdText.getText();
String subject = subjectText.getText();
String recipient = recipientText.getText();
String message = messageArea.getText();

boolean allFieldsCheck = true;

if (messageId.equals("") || subject.equals("")  || recipient.equals("")  || message.equals("")) {
    allFieldsCheck = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

all of the if statements can be replaced by:

```
allFieldsCheck = ! messageId.equals("");
etc...
```

Also, only your last if statement will have effect on the `allFieldsCheck` boolean variable; for example:

```
if (messageId.equals("") ){
    allFieldsCheck = false;
} else {
    allFieldsCheck = true;
}

if (subject.equals("") ){
    allFieldsCheck = false;
} else {
    allFieldsCheck = true;
}

if (recipient.equals("") ){
    allFieldsCheck = false;
} else {
    allFieldsCheck = true;
}

if (message.equals("") ){
    allFieldsCheck = false;
} else {
    allFieldsCheck = true;
}
```

is equivilent to

```
allFieldsCheck = ! messageId.equals("");
allFieldsCheck = ! subject.equals("");
allFieldsCheck = ! recipient.equals("");
allFieldsCheck = ! message.equals("");
```

only the last statement will have a say in the value of `allFieldsCheck`

what you want is:

```
allFieldsCheck = !(messageId.equals("") || subject.equals("") || recipient.equals("") || message.equals("")) //false if any of the top returns `true`
```

Comment: Those should be `allFieldsCheck = ! stuff.equals("");`

Comment: @tobias_k yup :) accidentally put weird logic :P

Comment: @tobias_k it is fixed

Comment: @tobias_k the ! flips the value, for example, if `messageId.equals("") ` is true, that means allFieldsCheck is false (meaning there are errors)

Comment: I know what the `!` does, and it was missing from some of your code blocks. I fixed it now. If you _did_ mean it the other way, feel free to reverse, but that would be wrong.

Comment: @tobias_k I apologize XD forgot to put it in :P apparently I can't count either,  i thought you said 4th code block

Answer (score 0):

You may not have the result that you are expecting... You are setting it to false and true for each check, therefor if it is false from the first check and true from the last check, your final result will be true. I'm guessing you are trying to do something like the following...

```
String messageId = messageIdText.getText();
String subject = subjectText.getText();
String recipient = recipientText.getText();
String message = messageArea.getText();

// Set to true
boolean allFieldsCheck = true;

// Foreach check and only set false so if one is bad, the allFieldsCheck is bad.
if (messageId.equals("")) allFieldsCheck = false;
if (subject.equals("")) allFieldsCheck = false;
if (recipient.equals("")) allFieldsCheck = false;
if (message.equals("")) allFieldsCheck = false;
```